# "scp | openssl" -- both need password

Tags: unix, pipe

Is there a way to sensibly do this:

```
scp user@host:/path/to/file /dev/tty | openssl [options] | less
```

without creating a file, and without having to supply either password directly in arguments?

The problem is, that both ask for password, but the order in which they start (and therefore also the order in which they ask for the password) is undefined. I'm not able to supply either password.

It would be OK to first finish `scp` and then start `openssl`, but without a temporary file.

Comment: Use keys instead of passwords

Comment: That would be an option for this particular problem, but what if I can't use keys?

Answer (score 1):

Although not especially nice, this seems to work:

```
mkfifo pipe && {
  scp user@host:/path/to/file pipe | openssl [options] -in pipe | less
#                                  ^
#                                  note the pipe
  rm pipe
}
```